# Tomcat Command Line Parameter for Hostname

Tags: tomcat, command-line, parameters, port

I am looking for a possibility to set the hostname of a running tomcat server via commandline.

Something like: java -jar -hostname="hostname"

I know that it can be done by using the Server.xml, but i am more interessted in the commandline-way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *can* set it in `server.xml` and configure it through the command line: `server.xml` supports variable substitution, so you can use `${configurableHost}` as hostname in server.xml, instead of any hardcoded value.

Then define `JAVA_OPTS="-DconfigurableHost=my.host.name ${JAVA_OPTS}"`, e.g. in `setenv.sh` and you're set. I've just tried this with the 3 ports that Tomcat occupies - works like a charm.

Note: While I typically advise to use `CATALINA_OPTS` for configuring the runtime settings, with this configuration I prefer `JAVA_OPTS`. This ensures that the shutdown process will also see your configuration - in my case the ports that I've changed.